# Sending an object from one component to another

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, vue.js

I have a component that shows you all your tasks, when you click one task I want the user to be sent to a component called `Task`, that then renders with the task the user clicked.

I've already tried using `$emit` from the `course` component to `app`, that then renders the task component, but this causes the `Task.vue` component to always be rendered in the `router-view`.

All the data is from a firebase database.
While I haven't included it, all components also has the variables declared in `data()`

`Course` component:

```
    <b-list-group class="listGroup" v-for="course in courses" v-bind:key="course.id">
      <b-button
        class="headline"
        disabled
        block
        variant="dark"
        style="opacity: 1"
        v-if="course.title"
      >{{course.title}}</b-button>
      <b-list-group-item variant="dark" class="clickableList" v-if="course.modul">{{course.modul}}</b-list-group-item>
      <b-list-group-item
        variant="dark"
        class="clickableList"
        @click="get(course.task6)"
        v-if="course.task6"
      >{{course.task6.name}}</b-list-group-item>
    </b-list-group>

  methods: {
    get(variable) {
      this.selectedTask = variable;
      this.$router.push('Task');
      this.$emit("task", this.selectedTask);

    }
  }
```

`App.vue`:

```
  <router-view @task="sendTask" />
      <div>
        <Task :parentData="childData" />
      </div>

  // Accepts data from course components
  methods: {
    sendTask(variable) {
      this.childData = variable;
    }
```

`Task` component:

```
<template>

      <b-button
        class="headline"
        disabled
        block
        variant="dark"
        style="opacity: 1"
        v-if="task.name"
        :item="task"
        :key="task.id"
      >{{task.name}}</b-button>


<script>
import firebase from "firebase";

export default {
  name: "Task",
  props: {
    parentData: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  watch: {
    parentData: function() {
      if (this.$router.currentRoute.name == "Task") {
        this.task = this.parentData;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The current code works. When you click a task you're sent to the `Task.vue` component and the code is rendered out, but it doesn't disappear when you leave the view.

There has to be a better way to do this.

Comment: I think this is where you're looking for: https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: I've had a look at vuex, but I'm not sure if it's a bit overkill for this project. The project will in total have around 200 tasks, that around 50 people will have access to.

Comment: Other thing is that you push the task as param with your route, or you push the id and then retrieve the task in your task component

Comment: I don't think vuex is overkill btw

Comment: I'll have a look at vuex then.

Comment: +1, from my experience you can put away vuex as far as you can, but anyway you will come to the central state management of some sort